# Userscript в extension, внедрение скрипта в код страницы сайта

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension, extension

Пишу расширение и столкнулся с проблемой, нужно по клику на клавишу клавиатуры вызывать окошко в которое пользователь может что то ввести и отправить мне.
Решил сделать это через `userscript` но почему то это не работает.
Вот пример:

`manifest.json`

```js
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_scripts": [{
    "exclude_globs": [],
    "include_globs": ["*"],
    "js": ["jquery.js", "user.js"],
    "matches": ["http://*/*",
      "https://*/*"
    ],
    "run_at": "document_end"
  }],
  "converted_from_user_script": true,
  "description": "Back top userscript extension for google chrome",
  "name": "backTopUserJS",
  "version": "1"
}
```

`user.js`

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  const div = document.createElement('div');
  const root = div.innerHTML = '<h1 id="modal_form" style="display:none; border: 2px solid red;">Modal</h1>';
  document.body.appendChild(div);

  window.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
    if (e.keyCode === 76) { //l
      root.querySelector('#modal_form').style.display = "block";
    }
  });
});
```

Подскажите, почему при нажатии на кнопку у меня ничего не происходит.  В манифесте ещё указан файл `content.js` и файл с `css`.

Comment: А вы не пробовали добавить `console.log` в ваш код, чтобы понять вызывается ли он вообще?

Comment: А вообще довольно странный у вас интерфейс. Пользователь может заполнять форму и случайно вызовет ваше окошко. Обычно всплывающие окна через кнопку расширения вызывают, для этого есть BrowserAction API.

Comment: @hindmost это просто тестовый пример, для удобства я решил использовать клавиатуру

Comment: @hindmost кстати, `console.log` ничего не показал

Comment: _для удобства я решил использовать клавиатуру._ Для чьего удобства, вашего или пользователя? По вашему это удобно - вызывать ваше окно через клавиатуру? Если для вас это удобно, это не значит что это удобно для всех. Большинство обычных пользователей используют клавиатуру в основном только для ввода текста

Comment: И не забывайте что ваш код (контент-скрипт) будет исполняться на **чужой** (не вашей) странице, которая тоже может использовать нажатия клавиш, и возможно те же самые, что хотите использовать вы. А узнать про это вы никак не сможете. Так что самое лучшее решение здесь - не использовать клавиатуру вообще. Контент-скрипт должен работать только с определенным контентом на определенных же страницах (и желательно только на конкретном сайте), а не лезть к пользователю со своими окнами к на каждой странице.

Comment: @hindmost  для удобства в примере. Я не собираюсь "лезть к пользователю со своими окнами к на каждой странице")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример имеет ряд проблем

**1.** Не имеет смысла использовать `"run_at": "document_end"` совместно с 
`document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ...)`.

Сам по себе смысл document_end в том чтобы посстараться запустить код контент-скрипта после срабатывания события DOMContentLoaded.

Для решения поменяйте в манифесте на `"run_at": "document_start"`

**2.** Данное выражение имеет неверный смысл:

```
const root = div.innerHTML = '<h1 id="modal_form" style="display:none; border: 2px solid red;">Modal</h1>';
```

В результате выполнения, `root` будет строкой (обратите внимание что там два оператора присваивания).

В итоге, верный код для контент-скрипта должен выглядить как-то так:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = '<h1 id="modal_form" style="display:none; border: 2px solid red; position: absolute; z-index: 99999; top: 0">Modal</h1>';
    document.body.appendChild(div);

    window.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
        if (e.keyCode === 76) { //l
          div.querySelector('#modal_form').style.display = "block";
        }
    });
});
```

Я немного добавил стилей для модального блока, чтобы он был более заметен. 
Блок появится в левом верхнем углу сайта.

Comment: Данный вариант работает, но скажите пожалуйста, а как можно реализовать это решение так, что бы в маниесте был указан `"run_at": "document_end"`? Без этого мой контент скрипт не работает

Comment: @МаксимБуяков Запросто, просто уберите прослушивание события `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded'...`. Сразу выполняйте создание элемента `div` и т д.

Comment: спасибо, вы мне очень помогли!